# Understanding Yealink VOIP phone configuration

Tags: voip, asterisk

I know how to connect my VOIP phone to asterisk. My asterisk server sometimes goes down so I will like to understand better how can I use a failover server. This guide:

http://download.support.yealink.com/download?path=upload%2Fattachment%2F2015-3-12%2F3%2F318dd26d-c535-4aa1-8be1-ca23b021d5dc%2FServer%20Redundancy%20on%20Yealink%20IP%20Phones.pdf

Explains how to do that.

Anyways I am having trouble understanding what does `Server Expires` and other fields mean in that guide. When I hover my mouse over the help icon it says:

> 1.It configures the registration expiration time (in seconds) of SIP server 1 for account X.

What does that mean? The default is 3600 (1 hour).

Another question I have is that asterisk acts as a proxy no? When does it make sense to configure an outbound proxy server?

[image]

Comment: Not think anybody know result. Need experement, it will depend of firmware version. In most cases it is less costly change hosting to something which not "go down". Setup failover system cost alot and not reasonable for less then 500 users.

Comment: expiration time is time between re-registrion. Registration used to say server where to found your phone for incoming(to phone) calls.

Comment: What messages are shown when you click the help ? icons next to the entries?